# MySQL composite primary key of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `classes_subjects` (
 `class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `day` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `slot` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `day` (`day`,`slot`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm building a system to set and display school class programs, but I'm having trouble with updating it.

Basically how it works is I have a class_id then for each class I have the days from 1 to 5 and slots from 1 to probably 10 or something which represent the subjects each day. Now in order to avoid building an insert and update functionality I thought I could use `REPLACE` syntax since they are not going to be updated frequently. The problem is that I don't know how to set up the indexes so that it will replace when `day` and `slot` of the row to be inserted are present. Currently it replaces whenever I insert a row with `class_id` that already exists.

What I need is to replace the existing record if the values I'm trying to insert match `class_id`, `day` and `slot`.

Not sure if I did a good job at explaining the problem, let me give an example. If the values in the table are such

```
class_id | subject_id | day | slot
1        | 1          | 1   | 1
1        | 2          | 1   | 2
```

Then I try to execute the following statement

```
REPLACE INTO `classes_subjects` (class_id, subject_id, day, slot) VALUES (1,3,1,1), (1,4,1,3)
```

The table should then look like

```
class_id | subject_id | day | slot
1        | 3          | 1   | 1
1        | 2          | 1   | 2
1        | 4          | 1   | 3
```

I hope you understand my problem because I really messed up explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key must be unique, so using class_id in this case won't work at all. The simplest "fix" for you would be to combine the class_id with the day/slot key and have that be your PRIMARY KEY be (class_id, day, slot). You might also slap a foreign key on class_id.

```
PRIMARY KEY (class_id, day, slot),
FORIEGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES class(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Oh my god, I thought of that but I don't know why I knew I can only set a composite primary key of maximum 2 columns. Obviously I was wrong, thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's actually a pretty common misconception. I think you can go up to 16 columns or something for a composite.